# find a function satisfies two conditions

Tags: functions

I need a function that satisfies the following two conditions. I have been thinking for a long time but still do not get any ideas.

1. $f(x)$ is a monotonically increasing function on the interval $[-1, 1]$ and $f(-1) = 0$, $f(1) = 1$.
2. $f^2(x) + f^2(-x) = 1$ for all $x \in [-1,1]$.
   I think it comes from $cosin$ functions but do not get any ideas fro construct it.

Comment: Would it make it easier to let $g(x)=f^2(x)$, then $g(x)$ is monotonically increasing and $g(x)+g(-x)=1$?

Comment: @Michael Thanks indeed. Get the function now. $\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}(x+1)}$.

Comment: Is the solution unique?

Comment: @user254665 not unique. Any function satisfy the two conditions will be fine. I think it for a while but Michael's suggestion is really cool.

Comment: An answer has just appeared with another solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(x) = \sin(\frac{\pi}{4}(x+1))$